# Total 147 test cases in my suite but after running in jenkins it shows report of 144 test, but I can see all the logs of 147 test case is showing

Tags: python, jenkins, robotframework, nightly-build

The count is 147 in the test suite, but after executing them in Jenkins server it shows total of 144 tests.

Where do these 3 tests disappear?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you compared the Log.thml with the results from Jenkins? When running outside of the context of Jenkins, do you observe the same results?